# Character encoding issue after changing servers

Tags: server, wp-config, encoding

I recently moved my WordPress-based site from DreamHost VPS to a Linode VPS running Debian + LEMP. After getting the site up again, I noticed many erroneous characters in posts; characters like " and - were being replaced with gibberish.

After doing some looking, it seemed clear that the issue was something related to character encoding.

I found a guide that suggested editing `wp-config.php` and commenting out the lines:

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');` and `define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

I did this and it fixed the problem, but I'm wondering if that was the best way to go about it. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I could be wrong here , but when I had a the same problem when moving servers it was do to saving the file in ascii instead of utf format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending the entire day working on this, I finally found a guide that worked perfectly:

- https://theblogpress.com/blog/seeing-weird-characters-on-blog-how-to-fix-wordpress-character-encoding-latin1-to-utf8/

Before that, I tried following @Rarst's information, tried exporting the database and manually cleaning it, tried the UTF-8 Sanitize Plugin with a modified version from here http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/ultimate-solution-to-weird-utf-character-encoding-problem (which actually worked pretty well, but didn't fix all the characters. And was probably a terrible idea).

Anyway, if any of you ever encounter this problem, check out the first link I posted. The procedure was pretty simple and basically came down to replacing `SET NAMES latin1` with `SET NAMES utf8` after exporting the database, then making sure to import the new cleaned database explicitly as UTF8.

Comment: UTF8 Sanitize plugin is working for me (though the plugin is fairly old - says not updated in 2 years as of this comment https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-utf8-sanitize/ ) fixing a database dump that was unclean.

Comment: the first link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution which worked for me...

just comment `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` in `wp-config.php`

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this would help.

Comment: How is this "another solution"? The exact same thing was already noted in the question; he tried commenting out those two lines in wp-config.php and it worked, but he was wondering if there was a better solution. Your answer adds nothing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question completely .... my mistake

Comment: Work like a charm !!!

Answer (score 1):

See [Converting Database Character Sets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) in Codex. Article has note about being completely rewritten at 3.0.1 version so info should be up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rarst. It was a little more extreme than I needed, I ended up just needing to replace an instance of `SET NAMES latin1` with `SET NAMES utf8` and re-import the database explicitly as UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

I transitioned my website files from an old to new directory and I was able to modify:

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

to

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

And this resolved the black diamond whitespace issue.